# Heroku apps automatically redirected to HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku, https

I have a Rails 4 app, deployed on Heroku. I want my app to be served via pure HTTP, not HTTPS. So I haven't done anything special to configure HTTPS redirect (at least I think so). But nevertheless, 
my app got a redirect to https every time I visit it. It behaves the same way in both cases, via subdomain.herokuapp.com and via my-subdomain.mydomain.tld, e.g. prepends https:// to the address. Which in turn (naturally) causes browser warnings about security.

Can I disable such behaviour?

By the way, mydomain.tld and www.mydomain.tld both work without this strange redirection, as well as a dummy app generated just for this purpose.

Answer (score 29):

It caused by `config.force_ssl = true` in production.rb

Comment: If this solved your problem you can accept your own answer. :)